# Use Link_to in Jquery code Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use  `linkt_to` (`<%= link_to 'address' , boat_path("'+boat_id+'") %>`) in my jquery code but I think because of the concatenation problem it does not work as I want.

Here is my Jquery code;

```
<script>

    (function ( $ ) {

      $('#map-canvas').mapSearch({
        request_uri: 'locations/show.json', 
        initialPosition: [ <%= @initlat %> , <%= @initlng %> ],
        filters_form : '#filters',
        listing_template : function(listing){ 
          var pics = listing.pic.image.thumb.url
          var address = listing.loc.address
          var boat_id = listing.loc.boat_id
          console.log(boat_id) // works fine
                    return '<div class="listing">'
                      +     '<h3>'+ '<%= link_to 'address' , boat_path("'+boat_id+'") %>' + '</h3>' // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
                      +   '<div class="row">'
                      +        '<div class="col-sm-2">'
                      +         '<img src= "'+pics+'" >'
                      +          '</div>'
                      +        '<div class="col-sm-5">'
                      +           '<p><strong>Address : </strong>' + listing.address+ '</p>'
                      +               '<p>'+listing.boat.year+', '+listing.boat.model+' '+listing.boat.captained+'</p>'
                      +               '<p>Reg Year: ' + listing.boat.year+'</p>'
                      +          '</div>'
                      +        '<div class="col-sm-5">'
                      +         '<p><strong>demo:</strong> '+listing.address+'</p>'
                      +         '<p><strong>demo:</strong> '+listing.address+'</p>'
                      +          '</div>'
                      +   '</div>'
                      +  '</div>';

                  },
        marker_clusterer : true
      });
    }( jQuery ));

  </script>
```

First of, I can not get the address, it renders the page by putting there the word address and the boat_id does not work. The link gets `http://localhost:3000/boats/'+boat_id+'` instead of something like `http://localhost:3000/boats/250`. But when I hardcode the boat_id part it works.

So, how should I change this;

```
'<%= link_to 'address' , boat_path("'+boat_id+'") %>' to show address itself and the boat_id as number.
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where is the above located?  Is it in an erb template, or a js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of ruby code, write html code that is

```
"<a href='boats/"+boat_id+"'>Address</a>"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but in this case boat_id returns nil. The url becomes `http://localhost:3000/boats/` without the boat_id

Answer (score 0):

`boat_id` is a javascript variable - which means it won't be available for use until your javascript code is executed, in the browser.

`link_to` is a ruby/rails method, which means it will get executed on the server.

So, at the time your `link_to` method is executed, your `boat_id` var won't be available.

There's no way around this - you'll have to ditch using `link_to`, and generate your URL/link manually in javascript, with plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose you want to have a link inside an element say

```
<div class="test">
</div>
```

jQuery code to add a link inside div

```
var boat_id = 2;  
$('.test').html("<a href='path/" + boat_id.toString() + "'>boat</a>");
```

The above jQuery code will create a link inside div.